# unable to create files from linux library via php

Tags: php, docker, permissions, command

I have an application in php that works on the docker. I would like to send a command from php code to container that should create files (some_dir/certs/cert.crt etc.). This command i run like this (by system/exec/shell_exec or symfony/process)

```php
system("traefik-certs-dumper file --source acme.json --dest some_dir --version v2");
```

When php run this code then directory has been created but not files, also i don't have any error.
This command works when i make it from terminal via `docker exec` but not from php. This is probably some permission problem between php and docker container, but i don't know how can i set it.
I'm trying to set in docker file this, but not working:

```
RUN chmod 777 /go/bin/traefik-certs-dumper
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
```

also standard command works like this:

```php
system("mkdir -p some_dir_1234");
system("touch some_dir_1234/some_file_1234");
```

How can I allow an installed library to create files?

Comment: Do you have any error in the logs, this will help to understand why the files are not created.

Comment: nothing special. system function return 0. no errors

Comment: Have you tried seeing the output using `exec()` - something like `exec("traefik-certs-dumper file --source acme.json --dest some_dir --version v2", $output); print_r($output);`

Comment: @NigelRen output contains ```array (
  0 => 'some_dir',
  1 => '├──certs',
  2 => '└──private',
)``` so only directories that command create, but without cert files which i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to find a solution. In a separate container, I had a process supervisor running, who saw this file, because it was mounted to the main application directory also.  What had to be done was to mount the file to the main container and the supervisor container.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
exec("traefik-certs-dumper file --source acme.json --dest some_dir --version v2");
```

intead of system()

Comment: exec and shell_exec also not helps